# In which direction does php print construct gets executed

Tags: php

I've came across an example in [print manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) of php.net. that stats.

```
   echo 3 . print(2) . print(4) . 5 . 'c' . 
   print(6) . print(7). 'b' .print(8) . 'a';
```

which prints `8a7b16145c12131`. But how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just got fooled by presence of concatenation operator `.` which made you assume that the only output from this code would come from `echo` and all other functions would only "contribute" to echo's argument. It is wrong, of course, because you assumed that `print()` somehow changed its behaviour and **returns** its output there, instead of **printing it out** instantly (upon a call) to the output stream. The only thing you concatenate there are strings and each `print()`'s ** return value**. And the latter, [according to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) is **always** "1". Change `print()`, to `sprintf()` and all the "magic" will be gone.

BTW it is good brainer - can keep busy for a while :)

**EDIT ON OP's REQUEST**

The "culprit" here is `print`. It is worth noting that it is not a real function but **language construct** which influences the way it is handled during evaluation. For example:

```
echo 3 . print(2) . 'c';
```

produces:

```
2c31
```

But if you move `print` into function like this:

```
function x($a) { return print $a; }
echo 3 . x(2) . 'c';
```

then the output will look more sane:

```
231c
```

If you care about details you will need to lurk into Zend Engine sources, but in general, such syntax is likely used for anything useful. Remembering `print` is tricky suffices.

And why we see "231c" anyway? It is because `echo` arguments needs first to be evaluated - without that PHP do not really know what to echo (or could know **partially**). So PHP goes more/less this way:

- get "3" to our temporary string
- call function `x(2)` - since this function does `print`, our argument ("2") will be **instantly printed to the output**. Function returns "1" because `print` always return "1" (see manual) so PHP concatenates "1" to so we now have "31",
- get 'c' and concatenate, so we now have "31c"
- `echo` our temporary string.

Note that in fact `echo` outputs '31c' only. Prefixing "2" is there because it is `print` output and we had not used LF (or `<br />` if you are not testing this in console) in meantime so all output goes into one line. If you change the code to use LF (or `<br />`):

```
function x($a) { return print $a; }
$f = 3 . x(2) . 'c';
echo "\n${f}";
```

then the output will be:

```
2
31c
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please explain in simple language, actually I'm a newbie in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

it prints '8' concatenate with 'a' and so on, right to left as the manual says. And echo prints that '1'

example

```
<?php
echo print(8) . 'a';
?>
```

prints 8a1

Comment: It'd be helpful to actually link to the manual, rather than just leaving a statement hanging mid-air: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php - as well, it should be noted that the 'answer' is actually a comment in the man page.

Comment: true, the answer is in the comment in the manual and i did not give the link of the manual because the questionnaire gave himself the same.